# This query looks clunky. Is there a better way to do this?

Tags: oracle

I've written a query that works, but looks super clunky. Also, the table only has a few hundred records in it right now, but will in the future have hundreds of thousands of records. It might get into the millions, but I'm not sure. So, performance might become an issue.

I'm wondering if there is a cleaner way to do this.

Thanks.

```
with objects as
(
select object_type, object_name 
from pt_objectshistory
where export_guid = 'PTGAA5V0H2U1XAQYFLQ0QXGWF0OY7Z'
),
distinct_objects as
(select distinct * from objects),
o_count as
(select count(*) ocount from objects),
do_count as
(select count(*) docount from distinct_objects)
select 
    o_count.ocount,
    do_count.docount,
    o_count.ocount - do_count.docount delta
from o_count join do_count on 1=1
```

Comment: [This](https://jonathanlewis.wordpress.com/2011/12/08/test-data/) and `dbms_random` will help you find out right now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no `group by`, so you just count the number of (distinct) rows in the table

```
select count(*), count(distinct object_type || object_name)
from pt_objectshistory
where export_guid = 'PTGAA5V0H2U1XAQYFLQ0QXGWF0OY7Z'
```

---

Thanks to [@MT0](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1509264/mt0), `object_type || object_name` could be ambiguous and discard distinct rows, when there are none like in `'abc' || 'def'` and `'ab' || 'cdef'`.

So depending on the data you have, adding a separator could be helpful, e.g. `object_type || ';' || object_name`.

---

You should also look on performance and test, if this solution (concatenating columns) is really faster than a count of a subselect/[CTE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hierarchical_and_recursive_queries_in_SQL#Common_table_expression).

Comment: Thanks. That's exactly what I was looking for. I tweaked it a little to:
select ocount, docount, ocount-docount delta from
(
select count(*) ocount, count(distinct object_type || object_name) docount
from pt_objectshistory
where export_guid = 'PTGAA5V0H2U1XAQYFLQ0QXGWF0OY7Z'
)

Comment: @P.B. If you have `object_type || object_name` of `'abc' || 'def'` then it will be counted as the same as `'ab' || 'cdef'`. This may mean that you undercount the number of `DISTINCT` rows.

Answer (score 0):

You may `group by` the `object_type, object_name` pairs and then sum up the result

```
select sum(gcount) as ocount, count(*) as docount
from (select count(*) as gcount, object_type, object_name
      from pt_objectshistory
      where export_guid = 'PTGAA5V0H2U1XAQYFLQ0QXGWF0OY7Z'
      group by object_type, object_name) temp
```